# Django user passing

Tags: python, django, web-applications

I am a newbie to python and django and I have to build a web app. It's supposed that after a user logs in he is redirected to another page where he chooses a project to work on. The problem is that AFTER successfully logging in when he chooses a project I get the "Invalid login credentials" error from the login view. I thought we were past this...
Here is the views file:

```
def login(request):
    context=RequestContext(request)
    if request.method=='POST':
        username=request.POST.get('username')
        password=request.POST.get('password')
        user=auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                auth.login(request,user)
                return render_to_response('ProjectLogging/main.html',{'user':user, 'project_list':Project.objects.all()}, context)
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Your account is disabled.")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Invalid login credentials.")
    return render_to_response('ProjectLogging/login.html',context)

@login_required
def logout(request, user):
    context=RequestContext(request)
    auth.logout(request, user)
    return render_to_response('ProjectLogging/login.html',{'user':None},context)

@login_required
def main(request, user):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    user=user
    if request.method=='POST':
        project=request.POST['project']
        if project:
            change=Change(user=user, project=project,starttime=datetime.datetime.now())
            change.save()
        else:
            HttpResponse("Choose a valid project!")
    else:
        HttpResponse("Choose a POST method (???????)")
```

This is the urls of the project:

```
urlpatterns=patterns('',
    url(r'', 'views.login'),
    url(r'^login/$', 'views.login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'views.logout'),
    url(r'^main/$','views.main'),
```

)

Also, I haven't mastered how views, urls and html files collaborate in django, so if you can suggest a site to study that I would be grateful. Finally, logout isn't working so if you have any idea about that I would be even more grateful. Thank you.

Comment: Obviously if you require more info or other files I would be happy to respond.

Comment: Are you familiar with Django's generic views? Using those is probably the quickest and easiest way to go here, rather than writing your own views. The `ListView` generic view should cover the project list, and the `login` view under `django.contrib.auth` should be fine for authentication. There's also a logout view.

Comment: Class based views and Django's generic views are brilliant, but hard to grasp. This site is kind of the missing bit in Django's documentation and is very helpful: http://ccbv.co.uk/

Comment: [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/class-based-views/intro/) contains simple introduction to class based views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Url patterns use regular expressions and return the first match. In a regular expression, a `^` signifies the start of a string, and a `$` the end. If neither is present, the pattern can be found anywhere in the string and it will still match. Now take a look at your first pattern.

```
    url(r'', 'views.login'),
```

This pattern can match anywhere in the string, and it matches if the string "contains" an empty string, i.e. *every* single string you can think of. All requests will be directed to your `views.login` view.

To fix it, you must use the pattern `r'^$'`. This will match the start and the end of the url path with nothing in between, i.e. only `www.example.com/` (the first slash is always chopped of). Then you can reach your other views at `/logout/` and `/main/`.

Comment: One more thing, it is good practice (anywhere on the web, not just in Django) to always redirect after a POST request. This prevents that the data is accidentally sent twice if the user reloads the page. As a POST request is supposed to have side effects, you really don't want that unless the user explicitly sends the data again.